# Переход на фрагмент при нажатии на элемент списка recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview

Использую в своем приложении список RecyclerView и хочу реализовать окно с подробностями выбранного элемента данного списка.
Т.е. грубо говоря, при нажатии на определенный элемент происходит переход в новый фрагмент, где находится информация о нём. это просто, видел как это делается с анимациями, хочу также.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш список должен иметь свой адаптер в котором есть функция `onBindViewHolder()`, и там можно обработать клик по итему:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WordViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    //... 

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

Дальше у вас есть фрагмент в котором будет отображаться информация о выбранном элементе. Так как вы не указали откуда будут браться данные то я просто объясню как передать данные в фрагмент и как их словить.

Ваш список находится либо в фрагменте либо в активности (опять таки не указано) и вам нужно используя интерфейс передать данные в фрагмент/активность для дальнейшей передачи в фрагмент. Делаем интерфейс:

```
interface Click {
    fun sendData(ваши данные)
}
```

дальше в конструкторе класса адаптера вам нужно добавить этот интерфейс:

```
class AAdapter(..., private val click: Click, ...) : RecyclerView.Adapter<...>{...}
```

и при клике вы просто вызываете интерфейс:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
click.sendData(ваши данные)
}
```

С адаптером мы закончили, а дальше вам нужно ловить передаваемые данные в фрагменте/активности. Для этого вам нужно сделать `imlpement` или `:` активностью этого фрагмента и переписать метод для отправки данных указанный в интерфейсе:

```
class List : Fragment(), ..., Click,...{}
```

у вас оно вероятнее всего будет подчеркнуто красным и предложит переписать метод интерфейса:

```
override fun sendData(ваши данные) {

    }
```

и дальше в этом методе уже передаете ваши данные в фрагмент для показа данных:

```
val your_fragment= Your_fragment()
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putInt("данные", значение)
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentContainerT, your_fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
```

в итоге получится как-то так:

```
override fun sendData(ваши данные) {
             val your_fragment= Your_fragment()
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putInt("данные", значение)
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contentContainerT, your_fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()
        }
```

ну и в том фрагменте где вы будете показывать данные итема нужно ловить данные в функции `onCreateView()`  так:

```
val bundle = arguments
if (bundle != null) {
//ловим данные
данные = bundle.getInt("данные")
} else {
 //если ничего не пришло             
}
```

в итоге будет как-то так:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
...
val bundle = arguments
    if (bundle != null) {
    //ловим данные
    данные = bundle.getInt("данные")
    } else {
     //если ничего не пришло             
    }

...
}
```

все работает довольно просто и в сети есть куча туториалов. Я привел код на котлине, так как я не знаю на чем вы пишете а я пишу на нем. Синтаксис схож, если будет что-то непонятно то пишите, поможем разобраться. Удачи :)

P.S. Если вы хотите чтобы вам точно ответили, давайте больше данных, какой-то свой код, чтобы было понятно что у вас кроме желания сделать есть еще и какие-то попытки (пусть даже не рабочие)

P.P.S. Дорогие пользователи ruSO если я где-то ошибся, пожалуйста в комментариях укажите на мои ошибки дабы я смог их исправить.

Comment: спасибо!! Вы мне очень помогли ;)